# How to remove Horizontal scroll-bar?

Tags: html, css, responsiveness

I am converting a Static Page to Responsive Page. When I resized my page to a lower width then horizontal scroll-bar and some amount of margin is also appearing in the bottom and right side of last div/Footer.

I have used overflow property in my code but still I am not getting the desired result.

```
body {
    margin:0%;
    padding:0%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}.
```

Due to some problem with imgur, I am unable to upload an image of my problem.

Please, suggest me some advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: still facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Open developer tools (F12) and locate the block that goes beyond the border of the page but the best, show your page code.

Comment: please suggest me how to remove unwanted margin in bottom or right of last div/footer

Answer (score 0):

`overflow-x: hidden;` os only for horizontal overflow: This still allows for a scrollbar at the right side for vertical scrolling.

`overflow: hidden;` is both for horizontal and vertival overflow.